# How to hold all the data bound, not just the data of the visible page

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

First, I'm sorry I do not have enough English Level.

My Grid shows 20 rows on a page. To use Excel export with client template, I used the following source found in the forum.

```
function excelExportWithTemplates(e) {
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    var colTemplates = [];
    var data = this.dataSource.view();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
        if (this.columns[i].template) {
            colTemplates.push(kendo.template(this.columns[i].template));
        } else {
            colTemplates.push(null); 
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < colTemplates.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (colTemplates[i] != null) {
                sheet.rows[j + 1].cells[i].value = colTemplates[i](data[j]);
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

For example, if I have a total of 100 data, only 20 data, the size of one view,
The remainder can not be applied.

it doesn't mean
ExcelExport don't work well, I mean ExcelExport with ClientTemplate do work just only 20rows. (my view page amount)

To do this, add data.Source.View
I tried changing it to total
Total is just counting the number,
No conversion has been made.

To convert all data
What should I turn .view into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`view()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/view) method will return only the rendered data on the viewport. Use the [`data()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data) method instead, which will return all dataSource's data:

```
var data = this.dataSource.data();
```